# Swipe gesture not being recognised

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, scenekit, uiswipegesturerecognizer

This is my first time using **UI Gesture Recognizers**. I am trying to implement it into `SceneKit`, to control the camera (isn't there a better way for custom controls?).

Here is a glimpse of what I have in my View Controller:

```
var gameView: SCNView!

/* ... */

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setup game
    /* ... */

    // Gestures
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeRightGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = .right
    gameView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGesture))
    gameView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
}

@objc func swipeRightGesture() {
    print("SWIPE!")
}
@objc func panGesture() {
    print("PAN!")
}
```

I can see that my `Pan` gesture works perfectly fine. However, my `Swipe` gesture does not seem to work at all. Removing the `Pan` gesture did **not** do anything, so there isn't a problem with the gestures fighting over priority.

Why is this not recognising my gestures? Have I forgotten some crucial things (like a delegate)?

Comment: Remove the pan gesture until you figure out the swipe gesture issue. Silly question but are you actually swiping in the correct direction?

Comment: @rmaddy I am swiping in the right direction!  I had the pan in the question just to show that it works, but swipe doesn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that when I set up my view, I set the camera control as such:

```
gameView.allowsCameraControl = true // Camera control
```

when it should really be:

```
gameView.allowsCameraControl = false // Camera control
```

I assume this is because the camera is overriding the gestures to the view, and I completely forgot about this! Works well as expected now, and hope it helps anyone in the future who also made this same small mistake.